# php class method return value of nameless function

Tags: php

Hello I have the following method. I would like to use a nameless function and change some data before the method returns, instead of creating a separate function to localize the results from the database query. I would also like the method to return the filtered data from the nameless function. What am I doing wrong in the following code?

```
public function getStats($request){

    // some custom input filtering

    $params = array('uid' => $this->uid);
    $reply = $db->get($query,$params);

    return function() use (&$reply){

        //localization of some strings

        return $reply;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the value returned by your anonymous function, you're returning the function itself. Try this instead:

```
public function getStats($request){

    // some custom input filtering

    $params = array('uid' => $this->uid);
    $reply = $db->get($query,$params);

    $myfunction = function() use ($reply){

        //localization of some strings

        return $reply;
    };

    return $myfunction();
}
```

Also, no need to pass `$reply` by reference.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP nameless functions are known as anonymous functions or closures. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

For more information [see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).